# SAS: how to disable 'always create backkup' when exporting to xlsx

Tags: excel, excel-2007, sas, export-to-excel

When I output a dataset to excel (using either the libname method or the proc export) and create an Excel 2007 file, the 'always create backup' option is automaticaly checked.

This way, whenever you make a change to that workbook and save, a .xlk file is created as backup.

Since this is not desirable, I would like to uncheck this option on creation of the document. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What code are you using for proc export to generate the excel file?  Is there any xlsx only feature you are accessing that would prevent you from saving the file into .xls first?  I've never seen this happen on a plain xls file.

Comment: I think this issue is irrelevant to SAS. You can disable this feature in Excel. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-excel/automatic-save-a-backup-copy-of-a-workbook-in/ab131770-b70c-4461-bae0-e2942b690545

Comment: @RobbieLiu you should move your comment to an answer...it seems like the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this issue is irrelevant to SAS. You can disable this feature in Excel.

> What you need to do is open any excel file and choose the "save as" option. When you are in the save as window, below the "File name" and "Save As Type" options, there is an option that reads "Tools" with a small drop down arrow next to it. Click on this drop down arrow and then from the dropdown list, choose "General Options".
>   In the window that pops up next, check the box that reads " Always create Backup"

source: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-excel/automatic-save-a-backup-copy-of-a-workbook-in/ab131770-b70c-4461-bae0-e2942b690545

Comment: This setting seems to be workbook specific. Normally I don't have the setting enabled for any workbooks, but when I export an Excel from SSMS, the setting is enabled.